# not able to get particular text box value using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

[image]

Here is my jquery function. i call this function on blue event. there are more than one records in list. i want particular **rojmel_id and weight** on blur event but i am not able to get. can anyone help me in this issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getweight(thisObj)
{
    var row        = $(thisObj).parents('.row');
    var rojmel_id  = row.find('.rojmel_id').val() != '' ? row.find('.rojmel_id').val() : 0;
    var dataString = "rojmel_id=" + rojmel_id;
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updateWt.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (data){
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

Here is my html code

```
{section name=sec loop=$clientArray}
    <tr>
     <td>{$clientArray[sec].rojmel_date}</td>
     <td>{$clientArray[sec].party_name}</td>
     <td>{$clientArray[sec].item_nm}</td>
     <td>{$clientArray[sec].marko}</td>
     <td><input type="hidden" class="rojmel_id" name="rojmel_id" value="{$clientArray[sec].rojmel_id}">
     <input type="text" name="weight" value="{$clientArray[sec].weight}" onblur="getweight(this);"></td>
    </tr>
{/section}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hope it work! and can you tell where you have been declared .row class.

Here is your solution: [Solution JSBin](https://jsbin.com/zanogaheyu/edit?html,output)

```html
<!-- add class to <tr> then --> 

{section name=sec loop=$clientArray}
    <tr class="row">
     <td>{$clientArray[sec].rojmel_date}</td>
     <td>{$clientArray[sec].party_name}</td>
     <td>{$clientArray[sec].item_nm}</td>
     <td>{$clientArray[sec].marko}</td>
     <td><input type="hidden" class="rojmel_id" name="rojmel_id" value="{$clientArray[sec].rojmel_id}">
     <input type="text" name="weight" value="{$clientArray[sec].weight}" onblur="getweight(this);"></td>
    </tr>
{/section}
</tbody>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getweight(thisObj)
{
    var row        = $(thisObj).closest('tr.row');
    var rojmel_id  = row.find('.rojmel_id').val() ? row.find('.rojmel_id').val() : 0;
    var dataString = "rojmel_id=" + rojmel_id;
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updateWt.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (data){
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: With This i Am able to get Id But Still Bot weight value. which is entered in textbox.

Comment: It's Working Bro Thank You So Much..

Comment: @PrashantOmVir NP!